# MYSQL how to sum of two concatenated fields

Tags: mysql, sum

Hi Do you have idea how to sum two defined fields? is this posible?

```
SELECT SUM(a) as total_a, SUM(b) as total_b, (total_a + total_b) as grand_total
FROM table
```

if not, how can i come-up with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a subquery.

```
SELECT sum_ab.total_a + sum_ab.total_b as grand_total
FROM 
  (SELECT SUM(a) as total_a, SUM(b) as total_b
   FROM table
  ) as sum_ab
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it inline as in:

```
SELECT SUM(a) as total_a, SUM(b) as total_b, (sum(a) + sum(b)) as grand_total
FROM table
```

Comment: Even simpler: `SELECT SUM(a) as total_a, SUM(b) as total_b, SUM(a + b) as grand_total FROM table`.